# Projection - once again

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shape file with nature preservation areas (Biosphärenreservate) in Germany. I think the projection  must be something like gauss-krüger zone 4 Pulkovo or something like that. When I reproject it to UTM-33N WGS84 it reprojects but is not exactly accurate. The borders don't quite match my other shape (the other file)

http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/biosph-res-2010.prj.zip
http://www.projektidee.org/images/extern/gebiet_UTM33.dbf.zip

Could anyone here help me with that problem. That would be nice!

best regards
desputin

Comment: Are you sure the projection of the other file is ok?

Comment: You may want to mark some of the answers to questions you've asked as "accepted", otherwise you might find you get fewer answers in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't see a "accept" button anywhere. (who created this stackexchange anyway? Half the time here has to be spent with burocracy!)

Comment: No I'm not  100% sure the biosphärenreservate are projected correctly.

Comment: Just a small wish: please less generic question titles...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening up `biosph-res-2010.prj` in a text editor, I get:

```
PROJCS["DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_3",
  GEOGCS["GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
    DATUM["D_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
    SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
  PROJECTION["Gauss_Kruger"],
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000.0],
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],
  PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
  UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

So you were almost right - I get the (apparently deprecated) `DHDN / 3-degree Gauss zone 3` (EPSG:31463)

What I think your problem is, is not one of projection, but of digitization and simplification. Overlaying `biosph-res-2010` (red) and `gebiet_UTM33` (blue) on Google aerial imagery gives me this:

[image]

So your biosphärenreservate line matches the coast quite closely, but the blue line has far fewer points, and isn't shifted by a uniform amount. So the quality of your data is questionable rather than your projection.